# Datatables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter 'business name' for row 0, column 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, bootstrap-5

I am using PHP Laravel, Bootstrap, MySQL Phpmyadmin. I am not quite sure where I have gone wrong since I have already checked the data attributes and all are correct or maybe I have missed something out.

business.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.apps')
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-12 text-left ">
   <h1 class="border-bottom border-bot pt-3">Businesses Information</h1>
</div>
<div class="Business-Content main-wrapper col-sm-12 text-left h-100  pr-0 pl-0 " >
   <div class="col-sm-12 pl-0 pr-0 search-bars" >
      <div class="topnav navbar navbar">
          <div>
         <button id="createbusiness" class="btn btn-success text-white " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#businessmodal">New Business <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
         <button id="bulkdelete" class="btn btn-danger text-white " style="margin-left:2px;" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>


          <div class="modal fade" id="businessmodal" name="businessmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="business-modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading"></h5>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                     </button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <form id="businessform"  class="modal-input">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="business_id" id="business_id">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">





                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" >
                              <label >Last Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Ex: Mandreza" value="" required="">
                              <span id="lastname_err" class="text-danger error-text lastname_err"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                              <label >First Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Ex: Rodrigo" value="" required="">
                              <span id="firstname_err" class="text-danger error-text firstname_err"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" >
                              <label >Middle Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middlename" id="middlename" placeholder="Ex: Exequiel" value="" required="">
                              <span id="middlename_err" class="text-danger error-text middlename_err"></span>
                            </div>





                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                           <div class="col-sm-6" >
                             <label >Telephone No.</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Ex: 1234-5678"  value="" required="">
                             <span id="telephone_err" class="text-danger error-text telephone_err"></span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                             <label >Mobile No.</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile"  placeholder="Ex: 0912-3456-789" value="" required="">
                             <span id="mobile_err" class="text-danger error-text mobile_err"></span>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>




                    
                    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" >
                              <label >Business Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="businessname" id="businessname" placeholder="Ex: Sari-Sari Store" value="" required="">
                              <span id="businessname_err" class="text-danger error-text businessname_err"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                              <label >Business Address</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="businessaddress" id="businessaddress" placeholder="Ex: Namulandayan, Lupao" value="" required="">
                              <span id="businessaddress_err" class="text-danger error-text businessaddress_err"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                              <label >Business Type</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="businesstype" id="businesstype" placeholder="Ex: Partnership" value="" required="">
                              <span id="businesstype_err" class="text-danger error-text businesstype_err"></span>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                <!----------------
                -->
                     </div>
                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                        <div class="item form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4">
                              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success business-button">Submit</button>
                              <a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 4px;" >Cancel</a>
                              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer text-white">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="search-container">
            <input class="global_filter" type="text" id="global_filter" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-sm-12 text-left h-100  pr-0 pl-0 pt-2 pb-2 text-white" >
         <div class="row pl-4 pr-4   ">
            <div class="col-sm-12 border border-bot ">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row pt-4 pl-4 pr-4">
            <div  class=" col-sm-12 overflow-auto display-nones ">
               <table   class=" bulk_action dataTables_info table business-table datatable-element business table-striped jambo_table bulk_action text-center border dataTable no-footer">
                  <thead>
                     <tr class="headings">
                        <th >
                            <input class="icheckbox_flat-green" type="checkbox"   id="check-all" >

                          </th>
                        <th class="column-title">Action</th>
                        <th class="column-title">Business_ID</th>
                        <th class="column-title">Last Name </th>
                        <th class="column-title">First Name </th>
                        <th class="column-title">Middle Name </th>


                        <th class="column-title">Mobile No.</th>
                        <th class="column-title">Business Name</th>
                        <th class="column-title">Business Type</th>


                        </th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  </tbody>
               </table>


            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>








<div class="modal fade" id="businessviewmodal" name="businessviewmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="business-modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading">View Business Data</h5>



             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
          </div>




          <div class="modal-body">
             <form id="businessviewform"  class="modal-input">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="business_idv" id="business_idv">











































                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">





                    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" >
                      <label >Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="lastnamev" name="lastnamev"   readonly>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                      <label >First Name</label>
                      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="firstnamev" name="firstnamev"  readonly >

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" >
                      <label >Middle Name</label>
                      <input type="text"  readonly class="form-control" name="middlenamev" id="middlenamev" >

                    </div>
                   



                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                   <div class="col-sm-6" >
                     <label >Telephone No.</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control"  readonly name="telephonev" id="telephonev" >

                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                     <label >Mobile No.</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly name="mobilev" id="mobilev"  >

                   </div>
                 </div>





                 <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Business Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                       <input type="text" id="businessnamev" readonly  name="businessnamev" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" >Business Address
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                       <input type="text" id="businessaddressv" readonly  name="businessaddressv"  class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Business Type
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                       <input type="text" id="businesstypev" readonly  name="businesstypev" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                 </div>









            </div>



@endsection
```

The data information cannot be entered in the system itself and this is what the Business Info Controller looks like.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//Models
use App\Models\business_info;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//Plugins
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use PDF;
class BusinessInfoController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (!session()->has("user")) {
            return redirect("login");
        }
        
        $business = business_info::latest()->get();
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = business_info::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('checkbox', function($row){
                        $chk = '
                             <input type="checkbox" class="flat icheckbox_flat-green text-center checkBoxClass" id="checked"  name="ids" data-id="'.$row->business_id.'" name="table_records">';
                        return $chk;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                        $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->business_id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info  btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 editBusiness"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                        $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"   data-id="'.$row->business_id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 deletebusiness"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                        $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->business_id.'" data-original-title="View" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 viewbusiness"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                         return $btn;
                 })
                   ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
                    ->make(true);





        }

        return view('pages.AdminPanel.business',[compact('business')]);
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'middlename' => 'required',
            'telephone'  => 'required',
            'mobile'  => 'required',
            'businessname' => 'required',
            'businessaddress' => 'required',
            'businesstype' => 'required',

        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>0,'error'=>$validator->errors()]);
        }else{


        business_info::updateOrCreate(['business_id' => $request->business_id],
        ['lastname' => $request->lastname,
        'firstname' => $request->firstname,
        'middlename'=> $request->middlename,
        'telephone_no'=>$request->telephone,
        'mobile_no'=>$request->mobile,
        'businessname'=>$request->businessname,
        'businessaddress'=>$request->businessaddress,
        'businesstype'=>$request->businesstype]);




        return response()->json(['status'=>1,'success'=>'Business saved successfully.']);
        }

    }

    public function budget($business_id)
    {
        $budget_involve = DB::table('budget_involves')
        ->where('business_id','=',$business_id)
        ->get();
       return response()->json($budget_involve);
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $business_info = business_info::find($id);
        return response()->json($business_info);
    }
}
```

This is the web.php part

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//Business Module
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel\BusinessInfoController;

//Business Module
Route::resource('business', BusinessInfoController::class);
Route::get('business/budget/{business_id}', [BusinessInfoController::class, 'budget']);
```

And this is the custom.js part

```
// business show table
var table = $('.business-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    dom: 'lrtip',
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: config.routes.business,
    columns: [{
            data: 'checkbox',
            name: 'checkbox',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false
        },{
            data: 'action',
            name: 'action',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false
        },{data: 'business_id',name: 'business_id', "visible": false,
        },{data: 'lastname',name: 'lastname'
        },{data: 'firstname',name: 'firstname'
        },{data: 'middlename',name: 'middlename'


        },{data: 'mobile_no',name: 'mobile_no'

        },{data: 'business name',name: 'businessname'
        },{data: 'businesstype',name: 'businesstype'

        },
        ]
});



 //Business module CreateBusiness POPUP
$('#createbusiness').click(function() {
    $('#submit').val("create-business");

    $('#businessform').trigger("reset");
    $('#modelHeading').html("Create Business Data");
    $('#businessmodal').modal('show');
    $('#lastname_err').html("");
    $('#firstname_err').html("");
    $('#middlename_err').html("");
    $('#telephone_err').html("");
    $('#mobile_err').html("");
    $('#businessname').html("");
    $('#businessaddress').html("");
    $('#businesstype').html("");

});

//Business module BusinessEdit
$('body').on('click', '.editBusiness', function() {


    var business_id = $(this).data('id');


    $.get(config.routes.business + '/' + business_id + '/edit', function(data) {
        $('#modelHeading').html("Modify Business Data");
        $('#submit').val("Edit Business");
        $('#businessmodal').modal('show');
        $('#business_id').val(data.business_id);
        $('#lastname').val(data.lastname);
        $('#firstname').val(data.firstname);
        $('#middlename').val(data.middlename);
        $('#telephone').val(data.telephone_no);
        $('#mobile').val(data.mobile_no);
        $('#businessname').val(data.businessname);
        $('#businessaddress').val(data.businessaddress);
        $('#businesstype').val(data.businesstype);

      //  $('#author').val(data.author);
    });


});
//Business module viewmodal
$('body').on('click', '.viewbusiness', function() {
    var business_id = $(this).data('id');

   $.get(config.routes.business + '/' + business_id + '/edit', function(data) {

        $('#modelHeading').html("View Business Data");
        $('#submit').val("Edit Business");
        $('#businessviewmodal').modal('show');
        $('#business_idv').val(data.business_id);


        $('#lastnamev').val(data.lastname);
        $('#firstnamev').val(data.firstname);
        $('#middlenamev').val(data.middlename);
        $('#telephonev').val(data.telephone_no);
        $('#mobilev').val(data.mobile_no);
        $('#businessnamev').val(data.businessname);
        $('#businessaddressv').val(data.businessaddress);
        $('#businesstypev').val(data.businesstype);





    });

});


//BUTTOM SUBMIT MODAL
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('Save');
    $(this).html('Submit');


    $.ajax({
        data: $('#businessform').serialize(),
        url: config.routes.business_store,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 1){
                $('#businessmodal').modal('hide');
                $('#businessform').trigger("reset");

                table.draw();
                }else{
                    printErrorMsg(data.error);


                }
        }/*,
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);

            $('#submit').html('Save Changes');
        }
        */
    });
});
//delete table
$('body').on('click', '.deletebusiness', function () {

    var business_id = $(this).data("id");

    if (confirm("Are You sure want to delete !")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: config.routes.business_store +'/'+business_id,
            success: function (data) {
                table.draw();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    }
});

//Bulk Delete check all
$('#check-all').click(function(){
     $('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});


// Bulk Delete Current Select
$('#bulkdelete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var total=0;
    $("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
        total += 1;
    });


    if (confirm("Number of Data to Delete: " + total)) {
    $("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
        var business_id = $(this).data("id");


       $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: config.routes.business_store +'/'+business_id,
        success: function (data) {
            table.draw();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });

    });
  }

});
```

Thanks in advance for those who will be able to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

change 'business name' to 'businessname' in custom.js

```
// business show table
var table = $('.business-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    dom: 'lrtip',
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: config.routes.business,
    columns: [{
        data: 'checkbox',
        name: 'checkbox',
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false
    }, {
        data: 'action',
        name: 'action',
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false
    }, {
        data: 'business_id',
        name: 'business_id',
        "visible": false,
    }, {
        data: 'lastname',
        name: 'lastname'
    }, {
        data: 'firstname',
        name: 'firstname'
    }, {
        data: 'middlename',
        name: 'middlename'


    }, {
        data: 'mobile_no',
        name: 'mobile_no'

    }, {
        data: 'businessname',
        name: 'businessname'
    }, {
        data: 'businesstype',
        name: 'businesstype'

    }, ]
});
```

Comment: It worked, the datatable warning is gone! However, I could not enter the needed data information in the actual system yet but when I put the data information in the phpmyadmin, it works and connects on the actual system itself. What else could be the problem in the code? Thank you so much.

Comment: what do you mean error insert data into database? @Jus

Comment: The bootstrap submit button is not working when I am about to enter a data information in the actual system. In the system, we also have a search button, modify business button, delete business button, and view business button that are not working. Is there something else that is missing in the code that I have provided out?

Comment: try check in right click -> inspect -> network, your submit button send request or not

Comment: I am already in the network part, how am I going to check the submit button send request, sorry, I am not familiar with this that much.

Comment: jquery.js?1157:4046 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/custom.js:45:25)
    at mightThrow (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3762:29)
    at process (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3830:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js?1157:4046

Comment: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: That is the warning that I saw when I inspected it.

Comment: clear the network list first, and try to click your submit button, if in the network name there is a business url, click on that

Comment: network tab like this https://wd.imgix.net/image/BrQidfK9jaQyIHwdw91aVpkPiib2/Q4AZ84qTJLEnfToJYVLR.png

Comment: After clicking the business url, what shall I find and do next?

Comment: click preview or response, and check message

Comment: Hello, Danz! Are you familiar with fixing an error in the bootstrap submit button since mine would not connect in the phpmyadmin. Hope to hear from you soon, thanks